# ¿Cómo abrir aplicación instalada en Windows 10 desde VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Buenas,

¿Cómo puedo abrir una aplicación UWP instalada en Windows 10 desde VB.NET? He probado con Shell y con System.Diagnostics.Process.Start, que si funcionan bien si pones el "Notepad" pero me dan error de archivo no encontrado si pongo una aplicación UWP.

El caso es que lo necesito para ejecutar desde VB.NET otra aplicación mía creada con VB.NET que se instala en un Windows 10, pero si no soy capaz de abrir una aplicación genérica no se si podré abrir la mía.

Comment: Podrías poner el código de como intentas abrir la aplicación diferente a notepad?

Comment: Hola Miguel, uso System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Powerpoint") pero con el nombre de la aplicación VB.NET que tengo instalada en mi equipo... El problema que veo es que necesito saber la ruta donde está instalado MiAplicación.exe. La he buscado con el Explorador y me dice que está en una ruta de este estilo: C:\Users\miuser\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\22L29GX8.209\4R1VKCBH.3KQ\prin..tion_da044da439c4a271_0001.0000_750fbdd233cace81

Comment: entonces no debería haber problema si pones la ruta directa hasta el ejecutable. Si te da error podrías editar la pregunta principal añadiendo al excepción que te esté dando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Iniciar aplicaciones conociendo su ruta

Claro que puedes abrir una aplicación usando `Process.Start`. Por ejemplo,el siguiente código abre una instancia del Chrome:

```vb
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe")
```

En este caso no necesita la ruta,ya que está en el path. Si no, puedes poner el path completo al ejecutable:

```vb
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
```

Si necesitas pasarle parámetros, puedes hacerlo tambien:

```vb
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "--incognito")
```

---

### Iniciar aplicaciones UWP

Iniciar aplicaciones UWP es un poco más complejo. En [Automatizar el inicio de aplicaciones de Windows 10 para UWP](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps) se dan algunas opciones. Una es la siguiente:

- Obten el nombre de familia de paquete(Package Family Name) de la aplicación a ejecutar (puedes obtenerlo abriendo un PowerShell y ejecutando `get-appxpackage MiNombreDePaquete`)
- Ejecuta tu aplicación usando la app `appxlauncher.exe`:

  ```vb
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.appxlauncher.exe" MiNombreDePaquete_ph1m9x8skttmg!AppId
  ```

Hay otras opciones que puedes consultar en el enlace que te puse antes.

### Iniciar aplicaciones instaladas mediante Click Once

Para ejecutar aplicaciones ejecutadas mediante Click Once hay varias opciones:

- Si la aplicación fue instalada desde una url (en una red local,por ejemplo), se puede ejecutar usando `Iexplore.exe` con la URL del archivo `.application` como parámetro:

  ```vb
  Process.Start("Iexplore.exe", "http://miServidor/aplicacion/aplicacion.application")
  ```

  Con esta opción, si la aplicación no está instalada, saltaría automáticamente el setup de la misma.
- Otra opción es buscar el archivo `appref-ms` que corresponde, sabiendo la carpeta del menu inicio donde se encuentra. Algo asi:

  ```vb
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
  sb.Append(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs))
  sb.Append("\")
  sb.Append("CarpetaEnElMenuInicio")
  sb.Append("\")
  sb.Append("MiAplicacion.appref-ms")
  Dim shortcutPath As String = sb.ToString()
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(shortcutPath)
  ```

Comment: Hola Pikoh, muchas gracias por la respuesta. En este caso en concreto de Chrome, funciona porque sabemos la ruta donde está el ejecutable, pero qué pasa con una aplicación tipo Modern App de Windows 10 cuya ubicación está oculta?

Comment: Si te refieres a aplicaciones UWP, deberías haberlo especificado y no poner `Chrome` como ejemplo. Edito la respuesta y te pongo una posible solución.

Comment: Lo siento, no veía clara la distinción. He dado con las UWP buscando por internet hace un rato. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: @RaúlPérez veo en tu comentario que la ruta de tu aplicacion era algo como `C:\Users\miuser\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\22L29GX8.209\4....`. Eso tiene pinta de ser una aplicación normal instalada mediante ClickOnce. Estás seguro de que no es eso lo que quieres ejecutar?

Comment: Sí, eso es lo que quiero ejecutar, pero piensa en que si instalo mi aplicación en los equipos de un cliente, de antemano yo no sé en qué directorio se instará mi aplicación (que efectivamente está instalada con ClickOnce). Es decir, que necesito acceder a mi aplicación ClickOnce desde otro programa y no se exactamente donde estará ubicada.

Comment: @RaúlPérez mira mi respuesta editada. Ahi te doy un par de opciones para ejecutar aplicaciones ClickOnce.

Comment: Ok, quizás lo que necesito es algún tipo de instalación distinta a ClickOnce que me deje un ejecutable accesible en algún sitio en el equipo del cliente. Esto mismo lo hice con otra aplicación que no llevaba paquetes de terceros (como Newstonesoft JSON por ejemplo), pero en este caso no me vale sólo con el ejecutable ya que hay que adjuntar las dll pertinentes.

Comment: @RaúlPérez yo he usado los métodos que te he dicho para ejecutar aplicaciones ClickOnce y funcionan perfectamente. Otra opción que no he puesto sería que la aplicación que llama a la otra haga una búsqueda en el disco para encontrar el ejecutable, bien hecho no debería ser muy lento. Pero yo usaría los métodos que te he explicado.

Comment: @RaúlPérez tambien puedes usar algun otro motor de instalación, como [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Pero yo seguiría usando ClickOnce...

Comment: He probado lo de acceder a la referencia de la aplicación en el menú de Inicio y funciona. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo! Tema cerrado.

Comment: @RaúlPérez me alegra haberte ayudado :)